# Mysql 'VALUES function' is deprecated

Tags: python, mysql

This is my python code which prints the sql query.

```
def generate_insert_statement(column_names, values_format, table_name, items, insert_template=INSERT_TEMPLATE, ):
    return insert_template.format(
        column_names=",".join(column_names),
        values=",".join(
            map(
                lambda x: generate_raw_values(values_format, x),
                items
            )
        ),
        table_name=table_name,
        updates_on=create_updates_on_columns(column_names)
    )
query = generate_insert_statement(table_name=property['table_name'],
        column_names=property['column_names'],
        values_format=property['values_format'], items=batch)
        print(query) #here
        execute_commit(query)
```

When printing the Mysql query my Django project shows following error in the terminal:

```
'VALUES function' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use an alias (INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) AS alias) and replace VALUES(col) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause with alias.col instead
```

Mysql doumentation does not say much about it.What does this mean and how to can i rectify it.

```
INSERT_TEMPLATE = "INSERT INTO {table_name} ({column_names}) VALUES {values} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {updates_on};"
```

Comment: I can't speak for python but I think `{values}` should be enclosed in parenthesis like `({values})`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Basically, mysql is looking toward removing a longstanding non-standard use of the values function to clear the way for some future work where the SQL standard allows using a VALUES keyword for something very different, and because how the VALUES function works in subqueries or not in a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause can be surprising.

You need to add an alias to the VALUES clause and then use that alias instead of the non-standard VALUES function in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, e.g. change

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=VALUES(baz)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2) AS new_foo
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz
```

(This only works on mysql 8+, not on older versions or in any version of mariadb through at least 11.0.1)

Note that this is no different if you are updating multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) AS new_foo
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz
```

From https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13325:

> According to the SQL standard, VALUES is a table value constructor that returns a table. In MySQL this is true for simple INSERT and REPLACE statements, but MySQL also uses VALUES to refer to values in INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements. E.g.:
>
> INSERT INTO t(a,b) VALUES (1, 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE a = VALUES (b) + 1;
>
> VALUES (b) refers to the value for b in the table value constructor for the INSERT, in this case 2.
>
> To make the value available in simple arithmetic expressions, it is part of the parser rule for simple_expr. Unfortunately, this also means that VALUES can be used in this way in a lot of other statements, e.g.:
>
> SELECT a FROM t WHERE a=VALUES(a);
>
> In all such statements, VALUES returns NULL, so the above query would not have the intended effect. The only meaningful usage of VALUES as a function, rather than a table value constructor, is in INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Also, the non-standard use in INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not extend to subqueries. E.g.:
>
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,2) ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE a=(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE b=VALUES(b));
>
> This does not do what the user expects. VALUES(b) will return NULL, even if it is in an INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.
>
> The non-standard syntax also makes it harder (impossible?) to implement standard behavior of VALUES as specified in feature F641 "Row and table constructors".

Comment: When using `SET`, as in: `INSERT INTO t SET a=1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=VALUES(a)`, no warning is given (MySQL 8.0.26). Is this usage also deprecated?

Comment: NOTE this query does not work if you reference a schema:
INSERT INTO schema.foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) AS new_foo
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION schema.new_foo does not exist