# How to fix VALUES() deprecation notice in INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, on-duplicate-key

VALUES() gives a deprecation notice in mysql 8.0 when used in a query like this

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=VALUES(baz)
```

This post showed how to fix it if you are updating a single row, but not a solution to multiple rows, which is what we use VALUES() for. [Mysql 'VALUES function' is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609570/mysql-values-function-is-deprecated/63609645)
From that post it says

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=VALUES(baz)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2) AS new_foo
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz
```

This is okay for single insert queries but I don’t know how to scale it for multiple inserts

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) 
VALUES (1,2) AS new_foo1,
VALUES (3,4) AS new_foo2,
VALUES (5,6) AS new_foo3
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz  #what to do here??
```

This looks excessive when inserting multiplerowsand not a replacement for the ease of VALUES(). Can someone tell me the correct way to fix the deprecation of VALUES() in this kind of query?

Comment: exactly the same for multiple inserts:  `INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) AS new_foo ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=new_foo.baz`   https://dbfiddle.uk/r5CsX0eO

Comment: That works but I didn’t expect it to. I thought the AS statement referred only to the value set it came after, but it applies to the entire set of value sets. I can see the original post has been updated to show this, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is in the manual. You write `values` *once*, then all the tuples, then `as` followed by the alias.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6) AS new
>  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = new.a+new.b;
> ```

This creates one alias to reference each row successively. Similar to a correlation name in JOIN syntax.

Comment: Although I looked at the manual first because I expected it to have an alternative, I did not understand its alternative because I did not know AS applied to all tuples. This is due to my newness to this.