# how to avoid values() with multiple values?

Tags: mysql

I can see in the log from my MySQL server that values() is going to be removed in future release...

How can I avoid values() after "on duplicate key update" when I have multiple values to insert to a table?

I have this example:

```
insert into my.table (id,text) values (1,'hello world'),(2,'hello again') on duplicate key update text=values(text);
```

How should that be written if I cant use "values(text)" but still want to insert 2 rows?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this answer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609645/1048425)

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you.