# Java, JDBC INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wild cards

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, sql-update, sql-insert

I Have a next SQL Query:

```
const val INSERT_OR_UPDATE_ITEM_SQL = "" +
            "INSERT INTO `items` (owner_id, object_id, item_id, count, enchant_level, item_location, item_location_data, custom_type1, custom_type2, duration_left, create_time)" +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) " +
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE owner_id=?,object_id=?,item_id=?,count=?,enchant_level=?,item_location=?,item_location_data=?,custom_type1=?,custom_type2=?,duration_left=?,create_time=?"
```

And this is preparation of PreparedStatement:

```
statement.setString(1, item.ownerId)
statement.setInt(2, item.objectId)
statement.setInt(3, item.template.id)
statement.setInt(4, item.count)
statement.setInt(5, item.enchantLevel)
statement.setString(6, item.itemLocation.name)
statement.setInt(7, item.itemLocationData)
statement.setInt(8, item.customType1)
statement.setInt(9, item.customType2)
statement.setInt(10, item.durationLeft)
statement.setLong(11, item.createTime)
```

The issue here is when i try to execute query :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=352) Parameter at position 12 is not set
```

This is because I have 22 Questions mark instead of 11 (because of ON CONFLICT UPDATE)

My Simple task is to make **INSERT or UPDATE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your query stands, (some of) the parameters need to be passed twice (once for insert and another for update). MySQL offers [the `VALUES(...)` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) to access the insert values by column name in the update clause - which is exactly there to save you that hassle.

Also: the `UPDATE` clause would be better expressed if it addressed only non-primary key columns, not all columns.

Assuming that your table has columns `owner_id, object_id, item_id, cnt, enchant_level` where the first three columns are the primary key:

```
insert into items (owner_id, object_id, item_id, cnt, enchant_level)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update 
set cnt = values(cnt), 
    enchant_level = values(enchant_level)
```

Or, if you are running MySQL 8.0.19 or higher you can use the new alias-based syntax (`values()` was an unfortunate name choice in MySQL, as it somehow conflicts with the homonym SQL standard row constructor):

```sql
insert into items (owner_id, object_id, item_id, cnt, enchant_level)
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) v
on duplicate key update 
set cnt = v.cnt,
    enchant_level = v.enchant_level
```

Comment: @GMDB It works as mention.. Thank you.. Was not able to google it for a half of a day.. THANK YOU.

Comment: the question is tagged both mariadb and mysql, so I will comment that, while VALUES still works in mysql 8, it is deprecated and an alternate syntax was added; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609645/17389.  Unfortunately, mariadb does not yet support that alternate syntax, through at least 11.0.1.

Comment: @Vetalll: welcome. As for research: the MySQL documentation is usually a good place to start, eg: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html