# MariaDB query error INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update, sql-insert

When I run below query in MariaDB, I get an error:

```
INSERT INTO price_2 (date_1,ticker,end_price,volume)
VALUES
('2021-01-02', '000001', 1340, 1000),
('2021-01-03', '000001', 1315, 2000),
('2021-01-02', '000002', 500, 200),
('2021-01-03', '000002', 1380, 3000)
AS NEW
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
end_price = NEW.end_price, volume = NEW.volume;
```

error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'AS NEW ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_price = NEW.end_price, volume
> = NEW.volume' at line 7 */

How can I get it to run without errors?

Comment: `AS NEW`  looks strange to me

Comment: Do you even have a unique key on the `ticker` column?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537710/is-there-a-way-to-use-on-duplicate-key-to-update-all-that-i-wanted-to-insert helps?

Comment: [Here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/) is the manual your error message asked you to check. Look at a form of `INSERT ... SELECT UNION ALL .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of an alias to refer to values being inserted in the `update` clause (here, `NEW`) is a new feature of MySQL, that is available from version 8.0.19 only. Starting version 8.0.20, the previous syntax (using [the `VALUES()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)) is considered deprecated, and planned for removal in a future version.

But, on the other hand, this feature is *not yet supported* in MariaDB - hence the error that you are getting. We have to use the `VALUES()` function here:

```
INSERT INTO price_2 (date_1,ticker,end_price,volume)
VALUES 
    ('2021-01-02', '000001', 1340, 1000),
    ('2021-01-03', '000001', 1315, 2000),
    ('2021-01-02', '000002', 500, 200),
    ('2021-01-03', '000002', 1380, 3000)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_price = VALUES(end_price), volume = VALUES(volume)
```

Related:

- [Mysql 'VALUES function' is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609570/mysql-values-function-is-deprecated/63609645#63609645)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124415/10676716